# Input sting for wrapped C++ function doesn't changing SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I make Python wrapper for C++ library.

mylib.i:

```
%module mylib
%include <std_string.i>

%{
    #include "mylib.h"

%}
%apply const std::string & {std::string &};
%apply std::string & {std::string &};

int getResult(const std::string& path, std::string& result);
```

mylib.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

myEnum {foo=0, bar};
myEnum getResult(const std::string& path, std::string& result);
```

After generating _mylib.so with following command:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -shared mylib_wrap.cxx -o _mylib.so -L. -lmylib -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7
```

I do next:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python Python 2.7.2 (default, Dec  6 2016, 10:43:39) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux4
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _mylib
>>> result= ""
>>> x = _mylib.getResult("somePath",result)
```

After execution of my function, `x` returns right respond of method. Also I have console output from my function. But result string doesn't changing. 
If I init result string with "some text", and call my function again, `print result`  return `"some text"`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at that code, you're passing the variable `json`, not the variable `result` so I would not expect it to change the variable `result`'s value.

Comment: @Petesh sorry, forgot change variable name after copypaste.

Comment: @Petesh but with right input parameter name, problem not gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get this to work inside your interface is to use `%inline` to create an overload that returns the result instead:

```
%module mylib
%include <std_string.i>

%{
    #include "mylib.h"
%}

%inline %{
    int getResult(const std::string& path) {
        std::string temp;
        const int ret = getResult(path, temp);
        if (ret != good) abort(); // TODO exceptions
        return temp;
    }
%}
```

You don't even need to show SWIG the real version of `getResult`.

There are other options (e.g. use an input typemap with numinputs=0 and an argout typemap to modify the return value), but they're more complicated and generally less portable to other languages.

Comment: @VolodymyrHnatiuk sure, or you can split it into `%{ %}` instead, but you end up writing bits of it (i.e. the declaration) twice then

Comment: So how? Maybe you have some example? @Flexo

Comment: @VolodymyrHnatiuk it's no different to modifying the code you had in the question - edit mylib.h to add another declaration, the declaration in the SWIG module file and add the same implementation I showed in my code into a translation unit you link into the shared object.

Comment: No you don't understand me. I can't change mylib.h, So I can't add another declaration of function to  mylib.h.
I asked you about ability to add mulib_module.h with another declaration of functions and create mylib_module.cpp with function implementation which now inside %inline %{%}. And with all of this call getResult(path, temp); from mylib.so .@Flexo

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with %inline then - it does exactly what you want very succinctly - SWIG puts it into the .cpp file for you automatically at the same time as wrapping it.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's not comfortable to change code in the interface file. And I thought that better to move code from inline scope into the additional .h/.cpp file where declare getResult(const std::string& path) which call getResult(path, temp);. And sad to swig wrapper call my functions in this way. @Flexo

Comment: There's no functional difference between putting it in another .cpp/.h file that you add over and above what the library author gives you (which you *can* do by just adding one more include and compiling one more .cpp file). Personally I prefer to put SWIG specific code into the SWIG interface file. When the project gets large enough or if I write reusable bits of SWIG stuff I split them out into more .i files and add them via `%include` directives.

Comment: I try to create mylib_m.h/.cpp. In .h file I declare just getResult(const std::string& path). In the .cpp file I put implementation of this method and add #include "mylib.h" and #include "mylib_m.h.
Than I add %include "mylib_m.h" to interface file and remove #include "mylib.h". But this trick doesn't work. @Flexo

Comment: And actually I agree with you, and I think it's a good idea to keep all overloads like I want, in interface file. But customer don't understand this and want move this overloads to .h/.cpp files which will be some part of wrapper. @Flexo

Comment: So like a result, I want give SWIG not real version of getResult method in mylib_m.h/.cpp files.  @Flexo

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter how much trickery SWIG does in this case, it can't get around the fact that python strings are immutable - once set, you can't change them.

The SWIG generated code looks vaguely like this:

```
std::string *arg1 = make a new std::string from path;
std::string *arg2 = make a new std::string from result;
result = (int)getResult((std::string const &)*arg1,*arg2);
resultobj = SWIG_From_int(static_cast< int >(result));
if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res1)) delete arg1;
if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res2)) delete arg2;
```

Note that it makes a new string from the strings passed in, and then nukes them at the end - after all, strings are immutable.

a lazy solution would be simply returning the json string e.g. an interface of:

```
std::string getResult(std::string &path)
```

would have the desired effect.

Now if you want a special return value, it's objects and all that would be entailed in that.

Comment: It's not a good. 
But can I wrapp my functions somehow in interface file. Define in interface some functions which will be call getResult function?

Comment: You should be able to do some form of wrapping to accomplish what you want. It's really because of the way python works that you can't get this interface to work as-is.