# Wrapp C++ library with SWIG with overloading called functions

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have compiled SWIG python wrapper for the following function:

**mylib.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

myEnum {foo=0, bar};
myEnum getResult(const std::string& path, std::string& result);
```

And interface:

```
%module mylib
%include <std_string.i>

%{
    #include "mylib.h"

%}
%apply const std::string & {std::string &};
%apply std::string & {std::string &};

int getResult(const std::string& path, std::string& result);
```

But I have a problem with function getResult. Because in Python strings are immutable . So I interested can I overload my function in interface file?
For example something like this:

```
%module mylib
%include <std_string.i>

%{
    #include "mylib.h"

%}
%apply const std::string & {std::string &};
%apply std::string & {std::string &};

std::string getResult(std::string& path)
{ 
   std::string result;
   getResult(path, result);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997992/input-sting-for-wrapped-c-function-doesnt-changing-swig/41027204#41027204